# Import Images From Domain To Subdomain?

Tags: php, image, subdomain

How do you link images from a domain to a subdomain in PHP?

I have a slider on my main site. I want to use the same images on my mobile site which is subdomained at m.mysite.com

I have tried to following code(which I use for my current slider):

```
<?php
$files = glob('images/gallery/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) {
  echo "<div class='slide'><a href=''><img src='" . $file . "' alt='description'></a></div>";
}
?>
```

Nothing happens. So I modify my code to this:

```
<?php
$files = glob('../images/gallery/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) {
  echo "<div class='slide'><a href=''><img src='" . $file . "' alt='description'></a></div>";
}
?>
```

This time it kinda works. It outputs this:

```
<div class='slide'><a href=''><img src='../images/gallery/1012081_1501438913448804_6782879489506876198_n.jpg' alt='description'></a></div>
<div class='slide'><a href=''><img src='../images/gallery/10177464_1495074060751956_373648277891171115_n.jpg' alt='description'></a></div>
```

All of the images are "broken".

When I click the img src in the source code I get this: http://m.example.com/images/gallery/1012081_1501438913448804_6782879489506876198_n.jpg

It seems as though the code is looking in the right directory, makes a div for each image, but then adds the m. to the beginning.

How can I fix this to where it does not look in the mobile directory for these images?

To make it simple the image link should be http://example.com/images/gallery/1012081_1501438913448804_6782879489506876198_n.jpg

Thanks guys.

Comment: Sub domain is another directory in main site. Simply copy the image to your sub domain and do what ever things you want

Comment: So basically the only solution IS to put the images in both? That kinda sucks lol. I was hoping to just upload the images to one directory and that was it. Thanks though. :)

Comment: or else upload image to cloud storage and call to your function

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions here:

1. If you want to deliver it from the mobile subdomain, the webserver
   needs it inside the webroot of the mobile website. You could symlink
   the image dir to the subdomain, so it has the same path for both
   domains. Maybe you'll have to tell your web server to follow
   symlinks, too.
2. Just serve the images from your main domain on the mobile website

A possible solution might look like:

```
<?php
$files = glob('../images/gallery/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$domain = "http://www.example.com/"; //your domain
foreach($files as $file) {
  $path = ltrim($file, './'); //strip ../ from the beginning of the path

  echo "<div class='slide'><a href=''><img src='" . $domain . $path . "' alt='description'></a></div>";
}
```

A side note: don't use `?>` at the end of your php files, you don't need it.  Cause if you accidently have a line break (or whatever) after that it will be printed out to the browser *imedeatly* and cause problems if you ever want to send a header...